# Play GLTF animation using OGL JS

Tags: ogl

Does anyone know how to load a "GLTF" file and play the animation? Using OGL JS?

I already can load the GLTF file but I can find an example of playing the animation, only this one: https://github.com/oframe/ogl/blob/master/examples/skinning.html

But that is loading 2 JSON files, one of them for the animation.

Answer (score 0):

ok, Looking more in detail the code examples, I found this: https://github.com/oframe/ogl/blob/master/examples/load-gltf.html and that actually plays animations, so now I just need to make a web component with typescript using this solution as a base.